# Autologout at random time after inactivity

Tags: symfony, session

I have a medical management created with Symfony 2.8 that at random time (from customer's email text) logout users after a bit of inactivity (this happen when they send a form (whatever it is)).

I have already increased the session time bringing it up to seven months.

The `cache_lifetime` is set to 0 ("when close your browser").

I have have tried to recreate the problem but neither me neither my collaborator have found the problem (never logged out).

Is there a way to figure out why the system logged out users or a function / controller / event to be called when there is automatic logout so that I can understand what the browser customer does ?

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely your server that times out the session and not Symfony.

Anyways the best way (imo) to make sure you keep sessions in a Symfony app is to store them in the database.

```
   # app/config/config.yml
    framework:
        session:
            # ...
            handler_id: session.handler.pdo

    services:
        session.handler.pdo:
            class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
            public:    false
            arguments:
                - 'mysql:dbname=mydatabase'
                - { db_username: myuser, db_password: mypassword }
```

Full doc article: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/pdo_session_storage.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Fingers cross.